# Using routeChangeSuccess only runs part of my function. Why is it different to running the function another way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

within my angularJS app I want to check a radiobox once the route loads. Using `$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {` I am having no such luck. The alerts all load using routeChangeSuccess but the checking of the radioboxes do not.

As a test I have create a button that when I click on it it runs testByClickingThis() via ng-click. This runs the same code and works, sending the alert and checking the boxes.

What is the difference and why? And how can I make the radiobox be pre-selected on route load?

The controller code is included here:

```
publicapp.controller('LCLoggedinController', function($scope, $route, patientAnswers) {
  $scope.language='';
  $scope.back = '#/';
  $scope.home = '#/lcloggedin';
  $scope.next = '#/lcloggedin';

  $scope.objectValue = patientAnswers.getObject();

  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    if($scope.objectValue.language=="english"){
      alert('a');
      document.getElementById("englishBox").checked = true;
    }else if($scope.objectValue.language=="italian"){
      alert('b');
      document.getElementById("italianBox").checked = true;
    }else{
      $scope.language='#/lcloggedin';
      alert('c');
    }
  });
  $scope.testByClickingThis = function () {
    if($scope.objectValue.language=="english"){
      alert('a');
      document.getElementById("englishBox").checked = true;
    }else if($scope.objectValue.language=="italian"){
      alert('b');
      document.getElementById("italianBox").checked = true;
    }else{
      $scope.language='#/lcloggedin';
      alert('c');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't a very "angular" way of achieving what you're doing.

Comment: $routeChangeSuccess its not used for doing things like that.... you can set the ng-model of your checkboxes and then use $scope.checkboxx = true based on the language value

Comment: Can be a number of things, but I think your variable `$scope.language='';` is not filled with anything. `$scope.objectValue = patientAnswers.getObject();` I don't know if this has returned yet when you invoke de `'$routeChangeSuccess'` callback. By the way, you should use a config file for this and work with resolves.